# Dialog does not Animate in Android

Tags: android

I've set up a Dialog using AlertDialog.Builder, and assigned it a style that has the animations in it, but the dialog doesn't animate upon being shown. It just cuts right into the frame.

Here is the code for the Dialog:

```
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

            RelativeLayout dialogLayout = (RelativeLayout)inf.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
            dialogLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            final Spinner typeSpinner = (Spinner)dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.type_spinner);
            final Spinner classSpinner = (Spinner)dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.class_spinner);
            final DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker)dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.date_picker);
            final EditText desc = (EditText)dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.dialog_edit);
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> typeAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.types, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            typeAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            typeSpinner.setAdapter(typeAdapter);
            getClassList();
            ArrayAdapter<String> classAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, classes);

            classAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            classSpinner.setAdapter(classAdapter);
            builder.setMessage("                Add an Assignment");
            builder.setView(dialogLayout);
            Dialog addDialog = builder.create();
            addDialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.PauseDialog;
            addDialog.show();
```

Here is the styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#469558</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>

    <style name="PauseDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/PauseDialogAnimation</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PauseDialogAnimation">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/expand_slide</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/shrink</item>
    </style>
```

And, for example, here is the expand_slide.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillEnabled="true"
android:fillAfter="true">
<scale

    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXScale="0.0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:duration="300"
    android:pivotX="100%"
    android:pivotY="100%"
    android:fillAfter="false"
    />
<translate android:duration="300"
    android:fromYDelta="10%"
    android:toYDelta="0"
    android:fromXDelta="-10%"
    android:toXDelta="0"/>
```

Can anyone help me out? I've been trying a lot of things, including instantiating the Dialog with the style ID as one of the parameters, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Thanks for anyone who helps out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to animations myself, but my understanding is that you need to build an Animation object 'myanamation'. In your case build the animation from your xml resource. Then from the View pertaining to the animation, call startAnimation(myanimation) after dialog.show().

```
    View mydialogview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.yourviewid);
    Animation myanimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.youranimationid);
    mydialogview.startAnimation(myanimation);
```

Hope this helps some.

Comment: That animates the dialog's layout, but not the actual dialog.

Comment: mydialogview can be any subclass of a view object: your dialog layout, a ViewGroup (like relative or linear view) containing other groups, or a single view instance like imageview.

Comment: I take it you are trying to animate the dialog as a whole, not just the stuff the dialog contains?

Comment: Yeah, im trying to animate the dialog as a whole.